# conjugate prior for exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, references, prior, exponential-distribution

If there is an exponential distribution 
$$p(x | \theta) = \theta\,e^{-x\theta}\mathbb{I}_{x>0}\, ,$$ 
what is a good conjugate prior? Also, will the posterior mean is a convex combination of prior and MLE

Comment: Have you checked in the literature? Any basic textbook will cover this case...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Conjugate_prior

Comment: Xi'an, can you point me to any relevant literature

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, this is a standard example. The conjugate prior is a gamma distribution on $\theta > 0$, this is given as example on p46 og Gelman et.al.: "Bayesian Data Analysis" (Third edition).

You can also find in the table at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior and a lot of other places.